# Draw page frame with words in margin

Tags: margins, framed

I am currently making exam papers using latex exam class. I would like to have the page frame with the word `Answer written in the margins will not be marked' on both margins, and the header or footer outside the frame like in the image below.

[page frame sample http://image.slidesharecdn.com/lsintrotest-131015190449-phpapp02/95/liberal-studies-practice-paper-for-beginners-5-638.jpg?cb=1381881942](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/lsintrotest-131015190449-phpapp02/95/liberal-studies-practice-paper-for-beginners-5-638.jpg?cb=1381881942)

Here's some code of mine. Appreciate your great help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\header{Prepared by Dexter}{}{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[3] Thanks for your help.
\question[2] \lipsum
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just look at one of the many packages that can place things globally on the page. `textpos`, `eso-pic` (low level) even `tikz` can do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1.5pt]
      ($ (current page text area.north west) + (-3mm,3mm) $)
      rectangle
      ($ (current page text area.south east) + (3mm,-3mm) $);
\node[rotate=90]
      at ([xshift=15mm] current page.west)
      {Answer written in the margins will not be marked};
\node[rotate=-90]
      at ([xshift=-15mm] current page.east)
      {Answer written in the margins will not be marked};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\header{Prepared by Dexter}{}{Page \thepage}
\footer{Answer written in the margins will not be marked}{}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[3] Thanks for your help.
\question[2] \lipsum
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice one.
A little problem here is that the words in the end of the lines are too close to the tikz box. I have tried to adjust the textwidth but it also reduces the size of the frame box. Can you do me a favour again?

Comment: @DexterWong Adjusted as per your comment.