# How can I create a double border/table around every page of the document excluding the headers/footers?

Tags: tables, formatting

I am a newbie to LaTeX... Outside of the title page and ending pages, I am trying to create a fixed size border/table that will be around every page (excluding the headers/footers) of the document.  Text also needs to be in the lower right.  The outcome needs to look similar to the following (text will be on each page):

[image: latex border]

I wasn’t sure what the best approach would be… I was trying to use framebox/fbox with a  horizontal line, but did not have much success.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX Take a look at [draw-page-frame-with-words-in-margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233749/draw-page-frame-with-words-in-margin/233760#233760). It's a similar question with a nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `TiKZ`, again, without special classes you can do something like this (with hints from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233749/draw-page-frame-with-words-in-margin/233760#233760)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[footskip=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,line width=.7pt]
 \draw ($(current page text area.north west)+(-2mm,2mm)$) rectangle ($ (current page text area.south east) + (2mm,-2mm) $)  ($(current page text area.south west)+(-2mm,-2mm)$) rectangle ($ (current page text area.south east) + (2mm,-8mm) $);
 \node at ($ (current page text area.south east) + (2mm,-5mm) $) [left]{UNCLASSIFIED};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Dummy Header}
\fancyfoot[C]{Dummy Footer}
\fancyfoot[R] {\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum 
\lipsum 
\lipsum 
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Note that I added the `footskip=1.5cm` option to the geometry package to adjust `footer` distance from the box. All parameters here can be adjusted for your case.

Comment: Thanks!  This worked great... I had to get the latest version of Tex installed as we had an antiquated version (something that is not easy to do where I work).  Thanks for pointing out the footskip as well as I needed to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `scrlayer-scrpage` for the header and footer you can add a layer containing the frame. Note that this suggestion needs an up to date KOMA-Script (version 3.16 or newer) but you can use a standardclass.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\chead*{Dummy Header}
\cfoot*{Dummy Footer}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  addvoffset=-5pt,addhoffset=-5pt, addwidth=10pt,addheight={10pt+2\normalbaselineskip},
  contents={\tikz[blue!50!green]{
  \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle({\layerwidth},{\layerheight});
  \draw[very thick](0,0)rectangle({\layerwidth},{\layerheight});
  \draw[thick](0,2\normalbaselineskip)--+({\layerwidth},0);
  \node[anchor=east]at({.975*\layerwidth},\normalbaselineskip){UNCLASSIFIED};
  }}
  ]{frame}

\addtolength\textheight{-2\normalbaselineskip}
\addtolength\footskip{2\normalbaselineskip}

%\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{frame}% add the frame
\blinddocument
\clearpage
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{@everystyle@}{frame}% remove the frame
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]